# For Chat window.whether i go for dynamic user control or client side div tag pop up window?

Tags: asp.net

i am developing chat application,for chat window what i need to use? dynamic user control or client side div tag pop up window(hide ,show property)?
recently i have use dynamic control but they were lost in every post back event.And if i recreate them with same id's then when user typing message in window,the focus gets lost when any postback event occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped write and maintain a simple chat window in ASP.Net WebForms a while back, the way we did it was to use some simple JavaScript making some HTTP requests to a page which had WebMethods on it.

The C# page contained a WebMethod for getting new messages from the server which was called from JavaScript running on a `setTimeout` loop. It also contained a WebMethod for adding new messages to the session.

If I recall correctly, some kind of queue was used per user involved in the chat session and all the method for getting new messages did was to map the user to the correct queue and take all the messages that were present at the time.

Hopefully this helps.